# Adjusting point values in Google Forms

Tags: google-forms

I currently have a google form that has questions from an internal audit for T-Mobile. I currently have all the point values assigned, but the issue i am running into is if we leave a question blank or mark it as N/A it is still taking points away from the total overall score. I am looking for a way to exclude these questions from deducting to the point total and have them taken off the total point value as well. Is this something that can be done in the script editor in the google form itself?